# Where to see full list of CKEditor plugins in CDN?

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, cdn

I include CKEditor source code into my app from CDN (see [CKEditor CDN docs](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/))

```html
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.0/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

I want to add some external plugins

```js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  config.extraPlugins = 'divarea,confighelper';
}
```

CKEditor also loads `divarea` plugin from [CDN](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.0/standard-all/plugins/divarea/plugin.js). But `confighelper` plugin seems to be missing in CDN and CKEditor complains with:

```
Uncaught Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "confighelper" was not found at "http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.0/standard-all/plugins/confighelper/plugin.js?t=42..."
```

so I need to download and unpack its source to my app from [CKEditor plugins page](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/confighelper). It would be cool to see what plugins are available in CDN.
I tried to see [CDN's plugins directory](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.0/standard-all/plugins/) but the resource responds with **Forbidden**

How to see full list of CKEditor plugins available in CDN?

Comment: Maybe from here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/tree/major/plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CKEditor presets](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/presets-all)

> The following table illustrates plugins provided by CKEditor
>   distributions, available in CKEditor CDN and the ​CKEditor releases
>   repository.